# Could not create table in database using php

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to create table if not exists, but the `result>0` is always false. i.e. it always displays `DATABASE ERROR!!!`

```
$tbl= "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS rec(
id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
Name VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL,
Email VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL,
Phone INT(11) NOT NULL
)";

$result = mysql_query($tbl);
if($result>0)
{
    $sql = "INSERT INTO rec (Name, email, Phone) VALUES ('$name','$email','$phone')";
    mysql_query($sql);  
    echo "<h3 style=\"color:blue\">Information entered.\n</h3>";
}
else
{
    echo"DATABASE ERROR!!!";
}
```

I should be looking into `mysqli` as `mysql` is depreciated. But I want this to be solved. There is nothing wrong with the html form and db configuration.

Comment: `AUTO INCREMENT` that's a typo. checking for errors http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php would have told you about it. it's missing the underscore. Here, RTM http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/example-auto-increment.html

Comment: voting to close as a TYPO

Comment: @Drew should i delete the question?

Comment: That's above my paygrade or call. I'll ask someone or maybe ask over in http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570 or refer to meta.stackoverflow.com  Once it hits 2 answers it is too late I believe. Plus one has to respect the work of the guy that spent the time to answer.

Comment: Make sure you do error reporting with PHP. And as you say, move to mysqli or pdo. PHP Manual page on [Error Reporting](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first Correct AUTO INCREMENT to AUTO_INCREMENT and for that you have to define a key. So right syntax is here:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS rec(
id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
Name VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL,
Email VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL,
Phone INT(11) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```